# Convert an object to DateTime considering System Settings

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a type object. Now I want to convert this object to a DateTime type. 
If the system settings are set to Swiss German (Switzerland), the following works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(obj, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If it's set to English US, the conversion fails (obj.ToString() returns 9/21/2019 12:34:00 PM).

I want the conversion to always work no matter what date format is set in the system.

Comment: How this object looks like? what's his properties?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't an overload of `DateTime.ParseExact` which takes a parameter of type `object`. Therefore, your code shouldn't even compile. Please provide a [repro].

Comment: What is a type object?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work no matter what language (and datetime format) is set in the system settings.

```
var s = obj.ToString(); // obj is of type object
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s);

// later I convert it to a specific format:
s = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: What is the *execution-time type* of `obj`? I suspect it's a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`, in which case you'd be far better off just casting rather than formatting and reparsing.

Comment: It might be a DateTime but I'm not sure. I do not know about the internals of that function. var dt = (DateTime)obj  will result in an error "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: Now is a good time to use a debugger then. If you can't actually launch it in a debugger, then at least log `obj.GetType()` somewhere. It's not a `DateTime` if the cast fails though.